# Looping a bin file

Tags: shell-script

I need to run an infinite loop command on a bin file

Here's what I need......

The bin files contents runs for 100 seconds
I need to either stop this @ 90 seconds start a new process and start the bin file again as if it was never stopped in an infinite loop.

Or run the bin file for its duration then loop when it's finished

Comment: Unclear: By "bin file", do you mean "an executable program"? What is the condition for stopping the program at 90 seconds vs. letting it run until it terminates naturally? By "stopping", do you mean _temporarily_ pause its execution and then resume it, or do you mean terminate the program and restart it?  What have you already tried and what was your issues with that?

Comment: Instead of asking about a "bin file" and then objecting to answers because of some mysterious "data stream", state in the question _what you are actually doing_ and _what your overall goal is_.  Don't assume that you can just blithely mention "the USB device" without explaining _what USB device_ and what on Earth its relationship to the question actually asked is.  Explaining that a "bin file" "runs 5.2mb data" is just incomprehensible.  Answerers cannot read your mind to find out what you are referring to by all these.

Comment: So please put all that in your question. Not here in the comments. Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout command does exactly what you require

```
timeout 90 /path/to/your/binfile
```

The first argument is the number of seconds, exceeding which the process will be killed. If the process ends earlier, then timeout command will do nothing.

You can add a while(1) loop to do this endlessly . In bash it would look like

```
 while [ 1 ]; do
   timeout 90 /path/to/your/binfile
 done
```

Comment: Please update the question with your experiments and more details about the stream. The current question just asks for an equivalent of timeout command